# Access to database in apscheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, apscheduler, aiohttp

I am trying to retrieve the database my app uses during the execution of a scheduled task in apscheduler. Apscheduler only allows functions it can find and pickle-able arguments, meaning I cannot pass the database into the function by reference.

```
scheduler.add_job(deadline_scheduler,
                  "date",
                  args=(app["db"],),
                  run_date=datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=1))
```

> ```
> TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
> ```

I have setup the scheduler so to use the same database as my webapp.

```
jobstore = SQLAlchemyJobStore(engine=app["db"])
jobstores = {"default": jobstore}
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)

scheduler.start()
scheduler.print_jobs()
```

Whilst running the function (in this case `deadline_scheduler`), I do not have access to either the scheduler object, the database engine nor `app`. This problem could be solved with `__main__.app` but that's a very inelegant solution and not something I want to be using in production code.

How can I get a reference to the database my app uses during the execution of my scheduled function without resorting to use of globals?

Setting up the `app` object:

```
def main():
    global app
    app = web.Application()
    setup_routes(app)

    conf = load_config(os.path.join("config", "config.yaml"))
    app['db_config'] = conf["db"]

    setup_cookiestore(app, SimpleCookieStorage())
    app["permissions"] = conf["permissions"]

    app.on_startup.append(setup_scheduler)
    web.run_app(app, **conf["webserver"])
```

Obtaining the database from `deadline_scheduler`:

```
import __main__


def deadline_scheduler(deadline):
    func_dict[deadline](__main__.app)
```

Whilst this works, it's very ugly and not really what I want to use

Comment: Mind to share what your `deadline_scheduler` function and `app` object look like?

Comment: @GustavoBezerra Edited question to provide that